# SHA256 HMAC does not give the expected answer

Tags: java, hmac, sha256

```
String stringToSign = "GET" + "\n" +
                    "webservices.amazon.com" + "\n" +
                    "/onca/xml" + "\n" +
                    "AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&ItemId=0679722769&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponeGroup=ItemAttributes%2COffers%2CImages%2CReviews&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2009-01-06";


    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
            "1234567890".getBytes(),
            "HmacSHA256");

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    mac.init(keySpec);


    byte[] result = mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes());
    String encodedResult = Base64.encodeBase64String(result);
    System.out.println("encodedResult: "+encodedResult);

    String urlEncodedResult = URLEncoder.encode(encodedResult, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%2B").replace("*", "%2A").replace("%7E", "~");
    System.out.println("ulrEncodedResult: "+urlEncodedResult);
```

This is for the REST authentication for AWS. The result I get is:
ulrEncodedResult: k1T%2FqvVoXgEvmdFhTEh71vLDznqEVCyKcslA5RRSB6s%3D

The expected result is:
ulrEncodedResult: M%2Fy0%2BEAFFGaUAp4bWv%2FWEuXYah99pVsxvqtAuC8YN7I%3D

All the exact steps for authentication are show here:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/rest-signature.html

Can anyone spot the mistake that I am making?

Answer (score 0):

One concern is that this:

```
"1234567890".getBytes()
```

and this

```
stringToSign.getBytes()
```

don't specify the character encoding used (e.g. UTF8). It'll be dependent on your platform or JVM settings, and that may be different from what you want (which is, I suspect, UTF8). I would prefer to use the `getBytes(CharSet)` variant.

Comment: Tried that, gives the same result unfortunately.

Comment: When I try .getBytes("UTF-8") and .getBytes() they give different results, like they are supposed to, but in general the result stays the same...

Comment: Does anyone have an idea??